# Why different types of list-item not allowed in Kindle format

Tags: ipad, kindle

In Kindle device the ordered list-styles (i.e. roman and alpha like that) is not support it displays only the numbered list. (i.e. 1,2,3) etc...

1. upper-alpha
2. upper-alpha
3. lower-alpha
4. decimal-leading-zero
5. lower-greek

Please solve my solutions,
Thanks,
Fazulur Rahiman

Answer (score 0):

Well, you did not specified your problem properly, but here is the list of the HTML tags supported by Mobipocket (that is: Kindle book format): http://www.mobipocket.com/dev/article.asp?BaseFolder=prcgen&File=TagRef_OEB.htm

HTH